# SSIS FTP task not sending or reciving 

Tags: ssis

I created an FTP task connection that's working fine, but I can only create and delete a directory. I can't send or receive files.

Comment: Can you provide code or any error messages?  You're asking for  psychic debugging with the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the problem further, I would recommend eliminating permission issues with the account.  You can do this by getting a free FTP client like FileZilla, PuttY, or Cute FTP and connecting to the server using the user name and password.  After you do this, then try uploading and downloading files with the account.  If the account works, then you have at least reduced the surface area of potential problems.

Please post more details about the issue such as error logs or screen shots of your settings to help us troubleshoot the issue with you.